# Copy rectangle selection in firefox

Tags: firefox, copy-paste

How do I select a rectangular area of text in firefox? My goal is to copy some columns from a html table.

I would like to select only the b and c columns (b1,c1,b2,c2 values) for this table:

```
|a1|b1|c1|d1
|a2|b2|c2|d2
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on a Mac), it lets you make that kind of selection.  It doesn't paste into Excel how you'd expect, though, so you'll have to see if that's useful to you.

Comment: Ctrl doesn't work on the above example in my FF 3.5.3.

Comment: The code above is not a table. http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/ for example works.

Comment: Pasting on Google Drive spreadsheet works perfectly

Comment: Just to be clear, this only works for tables.

Comment: OMG how did I not know about this feature! For ages I have copied the whole table into either a WYWIWYG editor, then edited, then grabbed the data,... or copied it into a text editor and clean up the data myself. This is soooo much easier! (VERY old post, and I'm ashamed I've never thought to look this up in the past ;))

Comment: It somehow stopped to work on FF 68.0.1 (32-bit). Am I alone with same problem?

Comment: @ReddySK working for me in FF 82.0.2 (64-bit).

Comment: @BobStein thank you. now it works also for me with 81.0.2 (32-bit)

Comment: Valuable tip :
How to select all the cells of a line (or all the cells of a row) :

Hold down the CTRL+SHIFT and left-click one of the cell, then move mouse cursor to the adjacent cell (still holding-down the left-click).

Useful on big table !

Answer (score 4):

See the Firefox extension [Table2Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1852) :

> Mozilla applications allow to select
>   rows and columns from a table simply
>   pressing Control key and picking
>   rows/columns with left mouse button.
>   The selection can be copied to
>   clipboard but the original table
>   disposition is lost making ugly
>   results when you paste the text on
>   datasheet applications (eg excel). 
> If
>   you want to paste data in Microsoft
>   Excel on OpenOffice Calc with correct
>   disposition simply use
>   Table2Clipboard. 
> Pasting in plain text
>   editors is also supported as CSV file
>   (but you can change rows and columns
>   separators from option dialog)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not supported anymore https://github.com/dafizilla/firefox-table2clipboard/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

this extension created by me for this purposes https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-range-select-and-co/klojbfbefcejadioohmnkhjmbmecfapg?hl=en

Comment: It seems the question is about Firefox, while this extension is for Chrome...