# Rectangular/box text selection in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

Is there a shortcut for rectangular selection in Firefox?

I'm not talking about the [table cell selection mode](https://superuser.com/questions/47109/copy-rectangle-selection-in-firefox), but about a mode like in *Notepad++* when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLFK6.png)) or in *Eclipse* when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

If there is no such option, then would it generally be possible for an add-on to add this functionality, or is there no chance unless Mozilla decides to add it?